# Render Large Texture To Smaller Renderbuffer

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a render buffer that is 852x640 and a texture that is 1280x720. When I render the texture, it is getting cropped, not just stretched. I know the aspect ratio needs correcting, but how can I get it so that the full texture displays in the render buffer?

```
//-------------------------------------
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBufferHandle);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBufferHandle);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferHandle);

    [oglContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];

    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &renderBufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &renderBufferHeight);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferHandle);
//-------------------------------------


static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,  -1.0f,
    1.0f,  -1.0f
};

static const GLfloat horizontalFlipTextureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};

size_t frameWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
size_t frameHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                            videoTextureCache,
                                                            pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_RGBA,
                                                            frameWidth,
                                                            frameHeight,
                                                            GL_BGRA,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &texture);


if (!texture || err) {
    NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);  
    return;
}

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture));

glViewport(0, 0, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight); // setting this to 1280x720 fixes the aspect ratio but still crops

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferHandle);

glUseProgram(shaderPrograms[PASSTHROUGH]);

// Update attribute values.
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, horizontalFlipTextureCoordinates);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// Present
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferHandle);
[oglContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

**EDIT**

I'm still running into issues. I've included more source. Basically, I need the entire raw input texture to display in wide screen while also writing the raw texture to disk.

When rendering to a smaller texture, things are automatically scaled, is this not the case with a renderbuffer?

I guess I could make another passthrough to a smaller texture, but that would slow things down.

Comment: You're going to want to match your viewport dimensions to your framebuffer's, not use your input texture dimensions for that.

Comment: @BradLarson Made an update. Is the (renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight) not the dimensions of the my frame buffer?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass IMAGE dimensions in "CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage" instead of your pixel buffer dimensions for width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, so the answer is that this was working all along ;) It turns out the high resolution preset mode on the iPhone 4 actually covers less area than the medium resolution preset. This threw me in for a loop until Brigadir suggested what I should have done first all along, check the GPU snapshots.

I figured out the aspect ratio issue too by hacking the appropriate code in the GPUImage framework. https://github.com/bradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 2):

First of all, keep `glViewport(0, 0, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight);` with `852x640`.
The problem is in your `squareVertices` - looks like it keeps coordinates that represent texture size. You need to set it equal to renderbuffer size.

The idea is that texture is mapped on your `squareVertices` rect. So you can render texture of any size mapped to rect of any size - texture image will be scaled to fit the rect.

[Update: square vertices]

In your case it should be:

```
{
0.0f, (float)renderBufferWidth/frameHeight,
(float)renderBufferWidth/frameWidth, (float)renderBufferHeight/frameHeight,
0.0f,  0.0f,
(float)renderBufferWidth/frameWidth,  0.0f,
};
```

But this is not good solution in common. From theory, the rectangle size on screen is determined by vertices position and transformation matrix. Each vertice is multiplied with matrix before rendering on screen. Looks like you don't set OpenGL [projection matrix](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glOrtho.html). With correct orthogonal projection your vertices should have pixel-equivalent positions.

Comment: Can you please post what the squareVertices should be?

Comment: I used your square vertices but it still doesn't work. I get a small square in the bottom right corner with the same cropped image I was seeing before.

Comment: In this case it's hard to propose anything. You can look at vertices data during rendering in `XCode OpenGL Frame Capture` tool (if you have new iPad/iPhone/iPod) - especially at vertices post-transform coordinates and transformation matrix.

Comment: See my answer, was coding alone for too long I guess. Thanks for telling me to check the Frame Capture. The square vertices actually didn't need any changing, but I am awarding you the points since you led me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I, Being new to OpenGL, remembers that the texture to be mapped should be in the powers of 2 by 2.
for eg the image resolution should be... 256x256, 512x512.
You can then SCALE the image using
gl.glScalef(x,y,z); function accordingly as per your requirements.
get the height and width accordingly and put these in your scalef function.
Try this, i hope this works.

Comment: There are ways to create a texture non power of 2 but in any case the function "CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage" should handle to create the texture. In both cases (power of 2 or not) after you have the texture you only use relative positions on interval [0,1] and scaling the matrix has nothing to do with cropping or anything. For instance, if you pass glOrtho(0, 1, 0 , 1...) and your texture image has the same aspect ratio as the screen, you will not need to scale the matrix to display that image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions. My answer can be validated from the info @[songhoa.ca.com](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)

```
glGenFramebuffers()
```

- void glGenFramebuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint* ids)

  - number of frame-buffers to create
- void glDeleteFramebuffers(GLsizei n, const GLuint* ids)

  - pointer to a GLuint variable or an array to store a number of IDs.It returns the IDs of unused framebuffer objects. ID 0 means the default framebuffer, which is the window-system-provided framebuffer.

*FBO may be deleted by calling `glDeleteFramebuffers()` when it is not used anymore.*

```
glBindFramebuffer()
```

**Once a FBO is created, it has to be bound before using it.**

- void glBindFramebuffer(GLenum target, GLuint id)

  - First parameter is The target should be GL_FRAMEBUFFER.
  - Second parameter is the ID of a framebuffer object.

*Once a FBO is bound, all OpenGL operations affect onto the current bound framebuffer object. The object ID 0 is reserved for the default window-system provided framebuffer. Therefore, in order to unbind the current framebuffer (FBO), use ID 0 in `glBindFramebuffer()`.*

---

Try using those, or at least **[visit the link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)** which could help you a lot. Sorry, i'm not experienced in OpenGL but I wanted to contribute the link, and explain the 2 functions. I think you can use the info to write your code.